# Media Queries - Landscape Mode on iPhone way too oversized

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using the following media query in my css:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

This looks fine on my older iphone 3g ... but when I change orientation from portrait to landscape.. it blows up.. way too big, way too wide.

I've tried this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px {}
```

Didn't help.

Any suggestions?

I would rather NOT put in a landscape specific query - I would like a generic one if possible.

(and Yes pinching the screen down kinda works.. but is not the user experience I am looking for.)

Thanks
JD

Comment: changed the title, I guess you want "queries", not "queeries" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a meta viewport tag? If not, you can use the following to tell the iPhone to report its viewport width as the width of the screen in px:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

[By default](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW27), the iPhone reports a width of 980px.