# Responsive website appears zoomed in with iPad

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

It appears that when I access my website via the iPad (the newest gen) it loads the responsive site correctly starting in landscape mode. When I switch to portrait, I can see that the site adjusts properly and it also looks fine. It's when I switch back to landscape again that the site appears to zoom in a bit and needs to be zoomed out.

I have the following code in the page to try to combat this, but it still occurs...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue with the help of this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434656/ipad-layout-scales-up-when-rotating-from-portrait-to-landcape

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems it can be fixed by removing the initial-scale property, or alternatively by JS

Look here: [Responsive site is zoomed in when flipping between Portrait and Landscape on iPad/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165460/responsive-site-is-zoomed-in-when-flipping-between-portrait-and-landscape-on-ipa)

here: [iOS zooming issue on responsive site from portrait to landscape break points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850534/ios-zooming-issue-on-responsive-site-from-portrait-to-landscape-break-points)

and here: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/01/09/zoom-on-orientation-change-fix-for-mobile-browsers-mobilizing-websites-with-responsive-design-and-html5-part-8/